# Unrecognized CPU by ARM gcc

Tags: c, linux, gcc, arm, archlinux

I want to compile a C file for stellaris board. (cortex m4)
But the compiler always throws the following errors:

```
Building file: ../main.c
Invoking: Cross GCC Compiler
arm-none-eabi-gcc -DPART_LM4F120H5QR -DARM_MATH_CM4 -DTARGET_IS_BLIZZARD_RA1 -I/home/erbal/src/stellaris -I/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.5.1/include-fixed -I/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.5.1/include -I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.2/include -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=softfp -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -MP -MF"main.d" -MT"main.d" -o "main.o" "../main.c"
as: unrecognized option '-mcpu=cortex-m4'
subdir.mk:21: recipe for target 'main.o' failed
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

Comment: -mcpu : this option is unrecognized by gcc. try -march or -mtune

Comment: Did you notice your makefile triggers `as` (assembler) which is not prefixed `arm-none-eabi`?

Comment: What should I do then? :)

Comment: -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m3 -march=armv7-m

Comment: does your make file triggers as directly, or is it coming gcc invocation. In first case fix your makefile, in second case fix your toolchain invocation.

Comment: according to change doc from 4.6 gcc supports cortex-m4. http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.6/changes.html

Comment: Please post the output of `arm-none-eabi-gcc --version` and `arm-none-eabi-as --version` .

Answer (score 3):

You need to install the arm-none-eabi-binutils package in addition to arm-none-eabi-gcc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `GCC -B` option to specify the prefix of the tool chain binaries, so the cross-compiler is used instead of the native.

Answer (score 0):

Need to put the arm-none-eabi-c++ or arm-none-eabi-gcc together with the whole gcc folder [e.g inside arm-none-eabi folder]. Because compiler will depend on others binutils component/files as well.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have the tool chain specific to ARM EABI at /usr/local/arduino-packages-1.6.8, ensure that /usr/local/arduino-packages-1.6.8/arduino/tools/arm-none-eabi-gcc/4.8.3-2014q1/arm-none-eabi/bin is readable and in the PATH environment variable and its contents have executable permissions.